# Is it possible to write a program in Python that takes info from a document scanner and sends it to something like the PeachTree Accounting software?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make my company's accounts payable system a little more automated and am wondering if I could write a program in Python that takes information (e.g. invoice number, date, company name) from a scanned document or PDF and then sends it to PeachTree Accounting.  The goal is to reduce the amount of data entry and simply scan the hard copies of the invoices, get the info that is currently manually entered, and place it in the appropriate spot in PeachTree.  I know this may be a shot in the dark but any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: The best approach would be to find a software consultancy with experience in this area and request a quote

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to solve two distinct problems.

First, whether you can extract information from a scanned document depends mostly on the format of the scanned document and the fonts used.  If you're talking about invoices in general -- that is, any invoice received from any party you do business with -- then this is likely to be an almost insoluble problem.  If you're talking about one invoice from one company printed in a guaranteed consistent format using OCR friendly fonts, then you might well be able to extract the data.  If you can induce the parties that send you invoices to modify them to contain bar-coded information, the problem becomes more solvable.

There do exist OCR libraries for Python but they won't work miracles.  In general, if you want to automatically process invoices you should require your suppliers to submit them in a machine readable format such as XML using an agreed-upon format.

The second problem you want to solve is whether you can write information into Peachtree.  That depends on whether Peachtree offers a published file format or, better, an API that allows access to their files.  A quick google indicates that they do.